# stop excel from formatting formula-result as date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string `5.3.4, 5.4.6, 5.4.7` and want to split it with `SMALL(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D32,",","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),COLUMN(A25))` to get all items.
My problem now is that Excel changes the result to a date `38051 38812 39177`. If i format the cells as text, the formula doesnt get evaluated.
I thought, there would already be a solution, but i probably don't have the right search terms.

Comment: You can try wrapping it in [Text function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) using "general format"

Comment: Was just evaluating the formula. When `FILTERXML` executes, the values get changed. So `TEXT` won't help, i'd suppose.